# Java Multithreading context switch on windows vs unix

Tags: java, multithreading

While I was going through a book "The Complete Reference Java Ninth Edition", I come to know about a fact related to context switching in java threads.
Following is the excerpt:

> In cases where two threads with the same priority are competing for CPU cycles, the
>   situation is a bit complicated. For operating systems such as Windows, threads of equal
>   priority are time-sliced automatically in round-robin fashion. For other types of operating
>   systems, threads of equal priority must voluntarily yield control to their peers. If they don’t,
>   the other threads will not run.

And a Caution to this :

> CAUTION Portability problems can arise from the differences in the way that operating systems
>   context-switch threads of equal priority

I was wondering if there is any way to avoid the problems related to portability in above cases.

**If I test my multithreaded code on windows and deploy it on Unix in production, would I be in trouble ?**

Please correct me if my understanding is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This text doesn't really say very much. It says "For operating systems **such as** Windows" but it doesn't specify which operating systems it considers "such as" Windows. I consider the text in the book misleading and not very useful in 2018.

In the earliest versions of Java, it was true that on most Unix-like operating systems, it was using "Green threads" which had this property.

Java has been using native threads on Linux for a very, very long time, so at this time, Linux should be considered "such as Windows" in this sense.

But the Java VM specification and the Java Language specifications do not guarantee pre-emptive threads, so it's still possible to make a JVM that is compliant with the specifications that doesn't have pre-emptive threads at the same priority. I don't know of any JVM implementations that are like that, however.

By the way, you didn't specify what type of "Unix" you were referring to, and you didn't specify which vendor/version of the JVM you were using - to give a 100% correct answer, you need to give that information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I am not stuck on this problem in my current project. But yes, i would consider latest available JVM and a good unix desto like red hat or fedora.